# How to use SyntaxHighlighter for inline code

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I am using [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) for my website.But how can I use it for inline code? I  mean when I use it for inline code it still shows the line number `1` and I want to remove it as it makes no sense to show line number for inline code

i.e

I want

"This is a java print code `System.out.println("Hello");`"

instead of

"This is a java print code `1 |System.out.println("Hello");`"

(notice the line number in second case)

I searched it on google but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a custom code block and style it yourself to achieve it:

**Algo:**

1. If Inline Display Custom Block
2. Else Allow `SyntaxHighlighter` to do its magic.

I have used the below code:

*CodeHighlighter.js*

```
import {Prism as SyntaxHighlighter} from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import {dracula} from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";
import './CodeHighlighter.css'
import {Card} from "@mui/material";

function cleanChildren(children){
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        children[i] = children[i].trim()
    }
    return children
}

export default function CodeHighlight({node, inline, className, children, ...props}) {
    var lang = "";
    try {
        lang = className.replace("language-", "");
    } catch {
        lang = "";
    }

    return (
        <div className='highlightRoot'>
            {inline ?
                (
                    <Card className='inlineCode' variant='outlined'>
                        <code >{children}</code>
                    </Card>
                )
                : (
                    <div>
                        <SyntaxHighlighter
                            language={lang}
                            style={dracula}
                            showLineNumbers={!inline}
                            startingLineNumber={1}
                            children={cleanChildren(children)}
                        />
                        <p>{lang}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>

    );
}
```

*CodeHighlighter.css*

```css
.highlightRoot{
    display: inline;
}

.inlineCode{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 4px;
    background-color: #4b4b59;
    color: white;
}
```

I have been using this in conjunction with ReactMarkdown library.

What I was able to achieve:

[image: SyntaxHighlighter Inline Code]

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration for turning line number on/off:
setting gutter attribute allows you to turn gutter with line numbers on and off. 
Here is [reference](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/configuration/) , Here is [DEMO](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/gutter.html)

Comment: But still the element acquires full line instead of being into a line with other text.I think its because of `<pre>` so I tried making it inline using `pre {style:inline;}` but no effect .How can I do that?

Comment: @InsaneCoder sorry, it seems difficult to implement what you want. Because the "Syntax Highlighter" change the original DOM structure. I've tried code like "<p><p>...<pre>code here...</pre></p></p>" but in the end the dom is like "<p>...</p><p>...</p><div><div>code here</div></div>", so in such a case, implement a inline code means we really need to figure how it convert the dom and make hack to it.